# Printer only working for wired computers, but not WiFi connected computers

Tags: networking, printer

I had to hard reset the router at work recently and though I set the WiFi names and passwords to what they were before (regular and guest WiFi), it threw the printer into an "Idle" state on every computer. The printer is wired to the router, so this confuses me a little.

For the wired PCs, all I had to do was go to "Devices/Printers" > delete the printer "Add Printer" and let it rediscover the printer and I was good to go, but WiFi connected computers can't find the printer whatsoever.

I couldn't find anything WiFi related on the printer

**Printer:** Toshiba E Studio 4505ac
**Computers:** Mostly PCs, 1 wired Mac and 1 WiFi Mac
**Setup:**  (green is good, red is bad)
[image]

Any help GREATLY appreciated,
Brandon

Comment: Have you done basic troubleshooting?  Can you ping the printer from a wifi computer? Are there VLANs?  Are all the devices on the same subnet?

Comment: I wonder if the router has "network isolation" or "wifi isolation" turned on by default which will  prevent wifi accesding wired devices like printer? The problem with needing to reinstall drivers on wired connections is probably because the IP addresses (including printer) chanded out changed when you reset the router.

Comment: Make sure your wireless security is WPA2 **only** (AES-CCMP only). Make sure original WPA/TKIP is completely disabled. Leaving original WPA available as an option can trigger bugs that break multicast based discovery protocols like you use to find printers.